# Beautiful Soup Error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, soap

```
allStat = rawDes.findAll("td")
```

This line gets me this result

```
<td>
<div class="head">Plays</div>
<div class="value">18,476</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="head">Ratings</div>
<div class="value">139</div>
</td>
```

so when I do following process on this result

```
array = []

for stat in allStat:
    single = []
    single['head'] = stat.find("div", "head")
    single['value'] = stat.find("div", "value")
    array.append(single)

print array
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
single = []
```

With the square brackets, you're creating an empty list.  List indexes must be numbers.  You need a key-based data structure, which is what Python's dictionary is for:

```
single = {}
single['head'] = stat.find("div", "head")
single['value'] = stat.find("div", "value")
```

Comment: Thanks, i am actually trying to create associative array here as can do in php not much familiar with python